# std::condition_variable gives 'std::system_error' what(): Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, c++11, pthreads

I wonder why this code gives runtime error. http://ideone.com/4a7v5A

I tried it on my local as well this is how I compile

```
g++ -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "/tmp/main.o.d" -o /tmp/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++ -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed -o /tmp/main.o -pthread
```

This is the code in the link

And this is the output

```
1 : Consumer-0joining
   2 : Procuding item 1
   3 : finished
   4 : Consumer-5 consuming item 1
   5 : Consumer-5 0 item left 
   6 : Procuding item 1
   7 : finished
   8 : Consumer-4 consuming item 1
   9 : Consumer-4 0 item left 
  10 : Procuding item 1
  11 : finished
  12 : Consumer-2 consuming item 1
  13 : Consumer-2 0 item left 
  14 : Procuding item 1
  15 : finished
  16 : Consumer-0 consuming item 1
  17 : Consumer-0 0 item left 
  18 : Procuding item 1
  19 : finished
  20 : Consumer-6 consuming item 1
  21 : Consumer-6 0 item left 
  22 : Procuding item 1
  23 : finished
  24 : Consumer-3 consuming item 1
  25 : Consumer-3 0 item left 
  26 : Procuding item 1
  27 : finished
  28 : Consumer-1 consuming item 1
  29 : Consumer-1 0 item left 
  30 : Procuding item 1
  31 : finished
  32 : Consumer-5 consuming item 1
  33 : Consumer-5 0 item left 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Drop `ulk.unlock();` in `consumer`. It's illegal to call `condition_variable::wait` with an unlocked mutex.

Comment: Also, your program will not terminate. Most consumer threads are sleeping when `run` becomes `false`, and won't ever wake up as the queue will never again become non-empty.

Comment: @Igor  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: And your point is?

Comment: @Igor if I do not unlock the mutex In current thread, other thread (notified one) won't be able to acquire the lock on condition variable. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: A `wait()` call unlocks the mutex for the duration of the wait, and relocks it afterwards. The very article you keep citing (but apparently haven't actually read) states that in no uncertain terms. This is why it's illegal to call `wait()` with the unlocked mutex; it would try to unlock a mutex the thread doesn't in fact own.

Comment: But why In sample code there, in worker_thread, it is unlocked before notify call ?

Comment: There's a comment right above explaining why: it's somewhat better for performance. `notify*` works whether called under lock or outside of it, but calling it under lock results in some overhead on the woken-up thread. However, the example doesn't try to call `wait()` with an unlocked mutex, while your program does.

Comment: Hmm. So I moved the ulk definition inside while loop (or I could just remove unlock as you suggested). It works